# How to list featured products in the homepage in Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: cms, product-list, magento-community

Im trying to achieve what I though it would be a simple task, of adding a list of manually selected products, to be presented as a featured collection of products.

Tried several options, using custom attributes or data from hidden categories but none of those have worked so far.

Can anyone please recommend a link/solution for this?

Comment: Go with inchoo extension, it is best and works like charm...

Answer (score 1):

You can install this extension provided by inchoo, Just upload [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/featured-products-on-magento-frontpage/) extension in your magento and then you will be able to select the products as featured. all featured product list will be shown on http://yoursite.com/featured-products .

For showing featured products on homepage Inside your Home page content HTML add this: {{block type=”featuredproducts/listing”}} and click on the save page button, all description is given on the [provided link][2]

Answer (score 0):

Luis, recently I was looking for solutions to achieve featured products goal. My requirements looked similar to one you are describing. I decided to use an [Ahead Works Featured Products 3 extension](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/featured-products-3.html) for that and installed that yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you could do something like this:

- Create a category that will not be listed in navigation menu (hidden)
- Assign products to it
- Create your own block that pulls data from that category (extend from **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List** and override the *_getProductCollection()* method
- create a template that will show these products (you can reuse code from **template/catalog/product/list.phtml**)
- call the block with that template in your CMS page (homepage or wherever)